# Mono: Where is HeapShot GUI for Windows?

Tags: c#, mono

Probably a stupid question, but - the [HeapShot page on Mono's website](http://www.mono-project.com/HeapShot#Obtaining_Heap_Shot) says:

> If Heap Shot does not have an installer or package for your operating
>   system, ...

Which to me implies that there exists somewhere on the interweb a page with download links for various platforms, in which Windows 7 may or may not be listed.

However, for the life of me - I can't figure out where that page lives.

I rather not get into building it now, I tried and I'm missing a ton of libraries, probably things I unchecked when I installed mono itself.

Before I (re)install GTK# and the rest of the shenanigans and build the damn thing, can someone shed some light please: Is there a simple download of a Windows build for Mono's HeapShot GUI?

Answer (score 0):

On the page it says that you can download their source from git and run xbuild to build the program for you or you can build it in Visual studio. I don't think there is a simple download of a build or if there even is a site where you can download them.